# bad gateway NGINX при настройке reverse-proxy в docker

Tags: nginx, docker, proxy

есть некий сайт который находится в контейнере и откликается на 80 порт. Мне нужно сделать реверс прокси в другом контейнере. Я создал Dockerfile:

```
FROM nginx:latest
COPY default.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/
RUN ["nginx". "-t"]
EXPOSE 80
```

и сам файл default.conf

```
upstream site{
server 172.17.0.2:5555;
}
server{
listen 80;
server_name site.com;
access и errorr log по стандарту
location / {
proxy_pass http://site;
}
}
```

контейнер с сайтом запускаю так - docker run --name site --rm -d -p 5555:80 repository
контейнер с reverse-proxy - docker run -d --name reverse --rm -p 80:80 reverse

docker ps -a:

```
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                         COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                  NAMES
ab1b69a58df7        reverse                       "/docker-entrypoint.…"   14 minutes ago      Up 14 minutes       0.0.0.0:80->80/tcp     proxy
e07d7fc9eaf2        repository   "/docker-entrypoint.…"   14 minutes ago      Up 14 minutes       0.0.0.0:5555->80/tcp   site
```

при попытке подключение к реверс-прокси получаю 502 ошибку:

```
root@debian:/home/user/docker# curl localhost
<html>
<head><title>502 Bad Gateway</title></head>
<body>
<center><h1>502 Bad Gateway</h1></center>
<hr><center>nginx/1.21.6</center>
</body>
</html>
```

1. Почему у контейнеров указывается адрес 0.0.0.0, а не 172.17.0.2 и 172.17.0.3 ?
2. что указывать в upstream nginx 0.0.0.0:5555 или 172.17.0.2:5555 ?
3. Как исправить 502 ошибку и настроить работу reverse-proxy ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Потому что в команде `docker ps -a` указывается не адрес контейнера, а настройки публикации (роутинга) портов. `0.0.0.0:5555->80/tcp` означает, что перенаправляться трафик будет с любого адреса на хост системе (т.е. 0.0.0.0) и порта 5555 на порт 80 внутри контейнера. Чтобы посмотреть IP контейнера можно воспользоваться командой `docker inspect <container name/id>`.
2. Указывать IP контейнера, полученного из пункта 1 (не самый лучший/удобный вариант).
3. Лучше всего это исправить объединив два контейнера в одну сеть. Проще всего это сделать через `docker compose`, но можно и руками (через команды в терминале), когда вы это сделаете появится возможность указывать не конкретные IP контейнеров в конфигурации `nginx`, а имена контейнеров (это работает из-за того, что в сетях созданных пользователем работает DNS, т.е. по имене контейнера будет резолвится реальный IP). Это хорошо тем, что по умолчанию у контейнера IP не статический (хотя статические IP и можно настроить) и после удаление контейнера (или запуска не другой машине) `Docker` может выдать другой IP и `nginx` не сможет найти его. Лучше на конкретные IP адреса не завязываться.

Выглядеть это будет примерно так:

`docker-compose.yml`

```
version: '3.4'

services:
  nginx:
    image: nginx
    build:
      context: ./nginx
    ports:
      - 80:80
  site:
    image: site
    build:
      context: ./node
    environment:
      NODE_ENV: production
```

При запуске через `docker compose up -d`, автоматически создается сеть между двумя контейнерами. Для примера я использовал небольшое node приложение. У вас в качестве site может быть что-то другое. Указывать `ports` у `site` не обязательно, т.к. у вас два контейнера будут находиться в одной сети и `ports` нужно только чтобы вы могли получить доступ из внешней сети (например, с хоста).

default.conf:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    location / {
        proxy_pass http://site;
    }
}
```

Можно просто указать имя контейнера и порт на котором запушено приложение (в данном случае это 80) и `upstream` не нужен.